# Why does `false && true || true` evaluate to true?

Tags: javascript, logic, short-circuiting

According to [MDN Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) page:

> false && anything is short-circuit evaluated to false.

Given this information, I would expect `false && true || true` to evaluate to false. However, this is not the case. The expected result (`false`) is only given when the statement is written like:

```
false && (true || true)
```

A coworker and I have tried to work this out and the closest thing we could come up with is that the statement is being evaluated by order of precedence. According to the [MDN Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) `logical-and` has a higher precidence over `logical-or`, suggesting that the condition is evaluated as if `false && true` were a single statement, which then moves on to determine the boolean condition of `false || true` which is then `true`. Written out, this would be:

```
(false && true) || true
```

Something is wrong here. It's either the documentation, the JavaScript parsing logic, or my interpretation.

### Edit:

I've added a bounty because none of the answers given truly understand the question. As stated above: the [MDN Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) page states exactly: "false && anything is short-circuit evaluated to false."

#### "anything" means "anything"!

Comment: This evaluates to `false`.  Are you certain it's not a part of a more complex operation?

Comment: nothing is wrong, the second form you show is the way it works, (false && true) evalutes to false so it ends up being: `false || true` which will give true because at least one of them is true.

Comment: I think you mean (false) as the expected result in the sentence, quote: The expected result (true) is only given when the statement is written like:

Comment: This is correct, and I've fixed it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: While you're emphatic '"anything" means "anything"!' is certainly correct - _any_ RHS expression is short-circuited and not evaluated - "anything" does _not_ mean "anything and everything."

Comment: Anything does mean anything. It means the very next thing, whatever it may be. As @BrianNorth put it, it doesn't mean everything. If it did mean everything, your program would stop as soon as it hit `false && ` because it would just short-circuit the rest of your program.

Comment: `(false && true) || true`  is different from `false && (true || true)`. which do you think your code represents? `false && anything` is false. but then you have an additional `|| true`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your confusion all comes down to a misunderstanding of precedence.

A mathematical analogue would be "Zero multiplied by anything equals zero."  Consider the following expression:

```
0 x 100 + 5
```

In any programming language, or a decent calculator, this evaluates to 5.  The "zero times anything" axiom is true - but the "anything" in this case is `100`, NOT `100 + 5`!  To see why, compare it to this:

```
5 + 0 x 100
```

It doesn't matter whether you add the 5 at the beginning or the end - the operator precedence rules remove ambiguity from the statement.

In JavaScript boolean logic, `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.  Since each operator is [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), writing

```
false && true || true
```

is exactly the same as writing

```
true || false && true
```

Comment: I think this best demonstrates the principle of that's going on. For me, though, this is still disappointing because of my previous understanding of short-circuiting.

Comment: @netinept - I believe my answer explains how short-circuiting behaves in a way you'll approve of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21394123/901641 (look towards the end of it.)

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Yes, I agree with your assessment. I'm waiting to reward the bounty and trying to keep an open mind since there are quite a few good answers, and it's difficult to choose the best one.

Comment: Wonderful explation, however I didnt believe it at first, had to check the precedence at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 11):

The language works by parsing an expression into abstract syntax tree. Your expression `false && true || true` gets parsed into this:

```
          ||
         /  \
       &&    true
      /  \
 false    true
```

Only *after* building the AST, the short-circuited evaluation can take place. The

> false && anything is short-circuit evaluated to false.

quote applies only to a valid sub-tree where `false` and `anything` are subtrees of `&&` node, like this:

```
       &&
      /  \
 false    true
```

which means only the `false && true` gets short-ciruit evaluated to `false` and resulting `false || true` is evaluated to `true`

Answer (score 9):

You are looking at precedence wrong.

&& is done first, then || so what it looks like is how you wrote it:

```
(false && true) || true
```

So the MDN link is correct.

Comment: What about short-circuiting then? It says "false && anything is short-circuit evaluated to false."

Comment: @netinept - And false or true is always true.  False and anything has to be false as it won't ever be true.  Precedence is the order things are evaluated, so you can just put parenthesis around the equations based on precedence and see what it looks like.

Comment: @netinept Operator precedence takes precedence to short-circuiting

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript will parse this expression this way:

```
1) false && true //evaluates to false
2) false || true //equals true. The first false is the result above
```

It's easy to trace how JavaScript parse this whole expression this way:

```
(function(){alert(1); return false; })() && 
(function(){alert(2); return true; })() || 
(function(){alert(3); return true; })()
```

Comment: I really like how you trace it.  I have never thought of writing anything that way.  If it works (and I assume it does), that is not only slick but something I need to look at more closely as it is a very interesting construct.

Comment: This is a neat trick, but doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

Let's put it this way. Somebody who wrote this MDN article phrased it quite badly/did small mistake

As you pointed out it says:

> false && anything is short-circuit evaluated to false.

And any reasonable person would assume that *anything* is logical expression of any complexity. However, this would be wrong reading (contradicting to boolean logic rules).

```
false && true || true == true
```

Two other answerers explained already why it's so. It's just an order of logical operators && and ||. First && is handled, next || is handled

Now, getting back to bad phrasing. What they should have said is following. Please notice additional parenthesis which I added.

```
false && (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to false.
```

I am using here parenthesis as a way to show that the rest of logical expression should have been evaluated independently of "false" part. If it's evaluated independently then short-circuiting it works fine because false &&  == false.

However, as soon as we have some expression which can't be evaluated independently then original phrasing doesn't work.

As example `false && true || true` can't be evaluated independently, because of order or logical operations. However `false && doSomething()` can.

Comment: I completely agree that the documentation should have `(anything)` instead of `anything`.

Comment: Actually, it's open source documentation. I believe if you create an account in there, you should be able to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this elementary arithmetic expression first:

```
A * B + C
```

Multiplication takes precedence, so the result is

```
(A * B) + C
```

Similarly, `&&` takes precedence, so

```
A && B || C
```

Is the same as:

```
(A && B) || C
```

As far as short-circuiting goes, the `Anything` that might be shortcutted is `B` if `A` is `false`. So if you had something like:

```
(false && takesALongTimeToDetermine()) || true
```

It would skip evaluating `takesALongTimeToDetermine()`

I should note this: **short-circuiting will never ever change the answer**. It is an optimization that is made. Since `&&` can only evaluate to `true` if both operands are `true`, it won't bother checking what the second operand is if the first is `false` because it already knows the answer is `false`. A reciprocal optimization is done with `||`: if the first operand is `true`, it'll return `true` without considering the value of the second operand. **This optimization exists so that your code will run faster - it will never change the answer**. The only reason it's mentioned in MDN at all is because if your && has one operand that will take a lot longer to calculate than the other, you aught to list it second. (It's also important because if `takesALongTimeToDetermine()` does something besides just return a value, IE, if it prints a log statement that you're expecting, you won't see it if the function is short-circuited. But this still has nothing to do with the answer returned by `&&`.)

Comment: Short-circuiting can change the answer if the short-circuited part has side effects. Consider the following: `function changeX(){ x=10; return false;}; x=5`. `false && changeX() || x` evaluates to 5 (because changeX is short-circuited), while `true && changeX() || x` evaluates to 10 because changeX is not short-circuited.

Comment: @Tibos - The `&&` short circuiting doesn't change what answer the `&&` returns. Your example is interesting, though - I didn't realize that `&&` and `||` don't return boolean values until I checked the MDN documentation just now.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the phrasing on [MDN Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) is a bit ambiguous.

You should not think of **anything** as *anything that comes after an `&&`*, but as *any right hand side operator to `&&`*.

`&&` expects 2 expressions: one on the left hand side of `&&` and one on the right hand side.

In your example: `false && true || true`, the false is the left expression and the first true is the right expression. The following `|| true` is not part of the what the `&&` operator will evaluate.

The short-circuit is meant to not waste cycles evaluating the right expression, if it can no longer effect the result of the logical operator.

In this example, it means that the right hand side expression (`true`) of `false && true` will be ignored (since `|| true` is not part of that expression)

So in execution, this is what will happen:

- Logical operator `&&` will be evaluated first
- It has 2 expressions, on both sides of the `&&`, which need to be evaluated
- First expression (`false`) evaluates to false
- Second expression (`true`) is short-circuited, because no matter the result, the logical operator can never result in anything but `false`
- `false && true` has been evaluated to `false`
- Logical operator `||` will be evaluated next (the result of `false && true` was `false`, so that makes for `false || true`)
- First expression (`false`) evaluates to false
- Second expression (`true`) evaluates to true
- `false || true` has been evaluated to true.
- End result: `true`

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably missing that operators only take a **single** argument on each side of the operator into account.

So from: `false && true || true` 
Only the first `true` is taken into account when comparing to the `false` .

So this evaluates to `false || true` and that finally evaluates to `true`

The 'anything' part of the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), might be a bit misleading in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this evaluates to true is because OR has higher precedence than AND, so it's equivalent statement would be:

```
(false && true) || true
```

Which is a tautology since `false || true` will always evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

> False boolean = 0;
>
> True boolean = 1;
>
> "&&" operator = multiplication operation;
>
> "||" = addition;

ok? So, if you've this:

```
if(true && false || true)
```

is equal to this:

```
((1 x 0) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is incorrect, and you're correct that the operator precedence is why it evaluates to true.  What you're missing is the meaning of `anything` in the context of an abstract syntax tree.

Because of the order of operations, you end up with a tree like

```
          ||
      /        \
     &&        true
   /    \
false   anything
```

The scope of `anything`, doesn't include the true on the right hand side of the tree.

You can see [some notes from Ohio State on ASTs here](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/software/2231/web-sw2/extras/slides/21.Abstract-Syntax-Trees.pdf).  They're applicable to every language.

Comment: You're right about that, however, I have edited the MDN documentation since posting this question to include the parentheses around the right hand expression. Knowing this may clarify things for you.

Answer (score -2):

The "false" and "anything"  in "false && anything" are absolutely referring to Javascript expressions/values (as diagrammed in @Erbureth's answer) , not to your source code. Here are examples to prove this statement:

Javascript code that "short circuits" (one on each line)

```
var a=false; a && 3
!1 && alert("Never!")
(1==2) && "x"
```

Javascript code that does not "short circuit" (one on each line)

```
<script>false && </script><p>Other page content...</p></body></html>
false && * x^.++@; true
"false && true"
```

Hopefully these inane examples help to clarify why it is meaningless to apply the rule you are citing to source code. The rule meant to be applied to the value/subtrees that result after parsing the source code (at which time order of operations have been applied)

Comment: I actually like these examples. It seems like they took some effort to be a little overly complicated, particularly: `false && * x^.++@; true` (WTF?)